# Extracting depth data from raster using lat and Lon

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am trying to get the maximum depth (`max_depth`) for a given lat and lot using this gebco (tiff file attached) and it keeps coming up with NA. In the past, this has worked so im not sure what is going wrong. The `site` is used to also extract temperature and nutrient data from WOCE files and that works. Is there something that I am missing in my code?

[image]

```
library(raster)
bathy <- raster("gebco0.5.tif") 

site <- cbind(125, -49)
extract(bathy, site)
#      [,1]
# [1,]   NA


show(bathy)
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 360, 720, 259200 (nrow, ncol, ncell) 
#resolution : 1, 1 (x, y) 
#extent     : 0, 720, 0, 360 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) 
#crs        : NA 
#source     : gebco0.5.tif
#names      : gebco0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no attached file, but your code looks good, and this works

```
r <- raster("https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8WSo.png")
extent(r) <- c(-180,180,-90,90)
site <- cbind(125, -49)
extract(r, site)
# 0
```

My guess is that the extent of `bathy` is not what you expect. Can you `show(bathy)` to us?

Now that we have `show(bathy)` we can see that you have an unexpected extent for lon/lat data: `0, 720, 0, 360 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)` . Such that you get

```
r <- raster("https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8WSo.png")
site <- cbind(125, -49)
extract(r, site)
#     [,1]
#[1,]   NA
```

From what I can see, it appears that you need to do:

```
extent(r) <- c(-180, 180, -90, 90)
```

And then things should work (as I already showed above). And if you know whereabouts "site" is, you can visually check that with

```
plot(r)
points(site)
```

Comment: This is what show(bathy gives me)class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 720, 0, 360  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : /Users/lavy/Desktop/Remineralisation model/gebco0.5.tif 
names      : gebco0.5

Comment: also the image is the file. Sorry I should have mentioned that. The image should download as a .tiff file (at least it does it for me)

Comment: In cases like this you should not use comments, but rather edit your question --- which I have done for you. And I will update my answer (and the image clearly is a png file?)